# How to increase Base64EncodeContent 1.9.2 group size limit in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to process 1MB base64 endoded data through `Base64EncodeContent 1.9.2 processor`, it is dropping few records and passing 700 Kb apprx. Is there any default size for Base64EncodeContent 1.9.2 processor or `is there any way to set the size value`

Comment: Are you encoding or decoding? And why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: actually i am decoding , the result content is having less records than source data set

Comment: is it one file or a set of flow files?

Comment: only one file, getting data inform of json element {Type:base64{data:base64endoceddata....}} and i am using data element as attribute to decode content.

Comment: Could it be possible you are loosing data while extracting it from json?

Comment: found the issue, while getting data from source end, it is having issue while encoding it..Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation on the size of the content. I believe the size of the encoded content may be smaller than the original size, so comparing size in and out is probably not a valid test. You could chain together two Base64EncodeContent processors where first is in "encode" mode and second is in "decode" mode, and the after second processor if you get same data that went into first processor, then you know it worked correctly.